Rendering only visible on Content Delivery site after Azure App Service restart
Steps to replicate the problem:

Add a new rendering with Personalization rules (we added this to our Footer Partial Design, but the problem surfaces when we add a rendering with or without personalization rules to any Partial Design or Page Design).
Publish to 'web'.
Changes are not consistently visible through the content delivery site, even though the 'web' database has been updated with the latest personalization rules for the rendering.

We now have to restart the Content Delivery Azure App Service to consistently see the changes. Our CD App Service is scaled out to 6 instances.
We are on Sitecore XP 10.2 with SXA.

We have tried clearing cache through sitecore/admin/cache.aspx
We don't cache content on a CDN
We don't have any Sitecore cache set up on the rendering itself:



We have this handler set on the publish:end event:

<event name="publish:end">
<handler type="Sitecore.Publishing.SmartHtmlCacheClearer, Sitecore.Kernel" method="ClearCache" resolve="true"/>


We don't have preventHtmlCacheClear set on our site definition.
We have no-store, no-cache set on the response header when pages are returned on our content delivery site.
We don't have any memory cache options set on the CD Azure App Service itself other than WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE which is set to 0.

We've seen this post, and have gone through what was suggested there: Content is not visible After publishing
Has anyone seen this issue before, and if so, what else could be causing it?

is the problem only with content with personalisation rules or on other content items?

The problem surfaces with components that don't have personalization rules too. I've updated the post above now.

Double check you do not have InstanceName setting populated on CD or only one instance will get cache clear event after publish.

Is it possible that you have recently depoyed a new web DB? Either way, I suggest reviewing the last updated time stamps in the properties table. more info here: https://deanobrien.uk/items-not-being-indexed-after-publish/

We haven't deployed a new web DB. We've worked around this by using the Footer partial design from the root site within the subsite Page Designs, instead of using a Footer partial design set up within the subsite. The personalization rules are working now.

It's just a shot in the dark but we had various issues effect or performance tracking, where Sitecore runs an A/B test for your personalization:
https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/102/sitecore-experience-platform/personalization-effect-tracking.html
In our case it was activated by default, which then caused "inconsistent" behavior, when we tried to test the personalization because you can't control who is put in test group and who in control group.
